# How do I detect if a 4x4 transformation matrix contains reflection?

Tags: matrices, transformation

We currently check if the determinant of the upper left 3x3 values is negative to detect reflection in a 4x4 transformation matrix but we are unsure that it works in all cases (any arbitrary 3D reflection plane).

What do you think about it? Do you know a different approach?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** *For closed objects (e.g. a Tetrahedron) it's easy to check if the 4x4 transformation altered it because it volume becomes negative. We are trying to detect this alteration even for open objects like a dome. Checking the 3x3 determinant seems to work fine but we wanted to be sure that it was the correct approach.*

Comment: I'm stumped as to what this all means... What does "contains a reflection" mean? What is a "3D reflection plane"? Do you mean a reflection in a hyperplane of 4-space?

Comment: I meant, how do we detect if the 4x4 transformation matrix contains a mirror/reflection by an arbitrary 3D plane? We can already detect if translation and scale are present but we are unsure if detecting a mirror/reflection as explained above is correct.

Comment: I simply can't find a sensible meaning for a matrix "containing a reflection". Here's a wild guess: Do you mean you want to check all possible submatrices found by deleting one row and one column to see if one of them is a reflection?

Comment: it makes sense to see if there any $3 \times 3$ blocks within a $4 \times 4$ matrix to be a reflection matrix of the form $I - 2(aa^T)/(a^Ta).$  what do you do you do when you find a reflection sub matrix?

Comment: For closed objects (for example a Tetrahedron) it's easy to check if the transformation altered it because it volume becomes negative. We are trying to detect this alteration even for open objects like a dome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your matrix is the augmented matrix representing an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) in 3D, then yes, the proper thing to do to see if it switches orientation is checking the sign of the top $3\times 3$ determinant. This is easy to see: if your transformation is $Ax+b$, then the $+b$ part is a translation and does not affect orientation, and $x\mapsto Ax$ switches orientation iff $\det A<0$ (you probably know this fact already).

If your matrix is a proper projective transformation (i.e., if it does not leave the point at infinity fixed), then I am not sure but my guess would be the determinant of the whole $4\times 4$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If $R$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix representing a reflection with fixed points on a 3D hyperplane, then his spectrum is $\sigma(R)=(1,1,1,-1)$, i.e. the eigenvalues are $1$, with eigenvectors on the 3D hyperplane and $-1$ with an eigenvector orthogonal to such hyperplane.

So this can be a test. But I don't understand how your test works.